# How to save the web page for offline in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

In WKWebView.h,
I came through this method:

```
-(void)createWebArchiveDataAtLocationWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *, NSError *))completionHandler NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT API_AVAILABLE(macos(11.0), ios(14.0));
```

I want to save the web page for offline, so for that what to write in the completion handler?

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892898/enable-application-cache-in-wkwebview/44333359#44333359

Comment: @Prakash,I want to know about method that i mentioned in the question.
And i didn't find that in the link you mentioned.

Comment: @ParasSaini see this WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10188/?time=1288